# Webview not opening link in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to open any link, like facebook.com for instance, but the link is not opening. What am I missing?

**MainActivity:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webID);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();                                    
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add, in `onCreate`, after your `webview` declaration:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

You may need to enable JavaScript depending on what else you need to do. For that use:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And do not forget to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In your manifest.

Comment: please can  you come in chat @Daniel K

Comment: Can you provide a link for it? I've only chatted once & I was given a link so I am not very familiar.

Comment: i dont now how i provide a link, please you can give a chat link or if you available on skype then my skype name is "sajid.h.glow"

Comment: Try this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114879/webview-not-openning-link-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

enable javascript:

```
webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

more info [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm)

Comment: pls let us in chat section for more detail @Reza Nazery